# wxpython get underlying GUI library

Tags: wxpython

Is there a method call in wxpython that can be used to find out which native graphical user interface (wxGTK, wxOSX/Cocoa, wxX11, wxMSW, ...) it relies upon?

I want to include floatable and dockable (wx.TB_DOCKABLE) toolbars in my software. However this is a GTK only feature. I would therefore like to include a check and only make the toolbars dockable if possible.

Or should I do a platform check instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `wx.version()`?
I don't have access to other operating systems but under Linux:

```
>>> import wx
>>> wx.version()
'4.0.1 gtk2 (phoenix)'
>>>
```

Looks like it should help.

Comment: I still have to use wxPython 3 for compatibility reasons with MayaVi. The version method does not exist yet in it. I have tried to access `wx.__version__`, but that simply contains `'3.0.2.0'`.

Comment: Using Python 2.7.12 on Linux  `wx.version()
'3.0.2.0 gtk2 (classic)'`

Comment: You are right. How bizarre.. No idea why it didn't work for me yesterday. This seems like a clean solution. Thanks!

Comment: The difference is between `wx.version()` and `wx.__version__`